# How do i create smart contract backed by a physical object?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development

I want to crowdfund a real estate Project on Ethereum blockchain (smart contracts) by creating my own token( Its a small scale Project) with the token holders gaining rental income plus any capital appreciation. What would be the simplest way to go for this? all suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Some tokens have value because they will be used to pay for a service. Investors profit by buying and selling tokens. Others tokens have value, because they represent an object. Let's say an entity will give you a token that represent a real world asset. Here the entity is the one backing the tokens, they will created with each deposit and destroyed with extractions. But you have to trust the good behavior of such entity.

Comment: Any updates about this?